# Dropdown list inside asp.net repeater loosing values on _ItemCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an asp repeater control inside an update panel. Below is the code for reference:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDisbursementEntry" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
    .
    .
    .

    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrCotrolsRow" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="rptrCotrolsRow_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrCotrolsRow_ItemCommand" >

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToolId" Text='<%# Eval("ToolId").ToString() %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtToolId_TextChanged" class="form-control" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" class="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged"  DataTextField='<%# Eval("DepartmentText").ToString() %>' DataValueField='<%# Eval("DepartmentValue").ToString() %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                </td>
                <td style="width: 90px">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCell" class="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCell_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMachine" class="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="false" EnableViewState="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRemovalReason" class="form-control" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnRemove" runat="server" ImageUrl="../remove-icon.png" ToolTip="Remove this row"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="../add-icon.png" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    .
    .
    .
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Below is the C# code behind for deleting a row for btnRemove:

```
protected void rptrCotrolsRow_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e){
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptrCotrolsRow.Items)
{
     TextBox txtToolId = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtToolId");
     DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
     row["ToolId"] = txtToolId.Text;
     TextBox txtPartProduced = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtPartProduced");
     row["PartProduced"] = txtPartProduced.Text;
     TextBox txtToolLifeAchieved = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtToolLifeAchieved");
     row["ToolLifeAchieved"] = txtToolLifeAchieved.Text;
     DropDownList ddlDepartment = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlDepartment");
     row["Department"] = ddlDepartment.SelectedValue;
     DropDownList ddlCell = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlCell");
     row["Cell"] = ddlCell.SelectedValue;
     DropDownList ddlMachine = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlMachine");
     row["Machine"] = ddlMachine.SelectedValue;
     TextBox txtQty = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQty");
     row["Qty"] = txtQty.Text;
     DropDownList ddlRemovalReason = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlRemovalReason");
     row["RemovalReason"] = ddlRemovalReason.SelectedValue;
     myTable.Rows.Add(row);

}
myTable.Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex].Delete();
rptrCotrolsRow.DataSource = myTable;
rptrCotrolsRow.DataBind();    }
```

Below is the C# code behind for Adding a row on btnAdd:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptrCotrolsRow.Items)
{
     TextBox txtToolId = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtToolId");
     DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
     row["ToolId"] = txtToolId.Text;
     TextBox txtPartProduced = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtPartProduced");
     row["PartProduced"] = txtPartProduced.Text;
     TextBox txtToolLifeAchieved = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtToolLifeAchieved");
     row["ToolLifeAchieved"] = txtToolLifeAchieved.Text;
     DropDownList ddlDepartment = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlDepartment");
     row["Department"] = ddlDepartment.SelectedValue;
     DropDownList ddlCell = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlCell");
     row["Cell"] = ddlCell.SelectedValue;
     DropDownList ddlMachine = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlMachine");
     row["Machine"] = ddlMachine.SelectedValue;
     TextBox txtQty = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQty");
     row["Qty"] = txtQty.Text;
     DropDownList ddlRemovalReason = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlRemovalReason");
     row["RemovalReason"] = ddlRemovalReason.SelectedValue;
     myTable.Rows.Add(row);

}
myTable.Rows.Add(myTable.NewRow());
rptrCotrolsRow.DataSource = myTable;
rptrCotrolsRow.DataBind();}
```

**Every thing is working perfect but when I am Adding/Removing a row, the drop down values are getting reset. Please help.**

Comment: how are the dropdowns bound in the first place? whatever binding you apply will need to be re-applied after every postback.

Comment: @ADyson On post back the values of the drop down list are not lost. It is only lost on ItemCommand i.e. while I am adding or deleting a row. The drop down list Cell gets its values based on Selected Item of Department and Machine Gets its values based on Selection of Cell.  I am unable to set the selected value for the Department.

Comment: you aren't trying to set the selected value for Department in those methods. You are trying to read it. Are you saying that `ddlDepartment.SelectedValue` is null? Or that when you return to the page that `ddlDepartment` has the wrong/no value selected? Or that there are no options at all in the dropdown? Does this problem apply to all rows in the Repeater, or only the one you just changed? Please clarify and be careful with your terminology.